# Java ItemListener for JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I have a JComboBox and an ItemListener which can detect when there is an item state change. I want it to listen for whether the FIRST item in the list is selected.

It is a list of usernames, with the first item always being  by default. However I need to know if the user selects the  item in case there is a username called  that gets added.

So basically I need a way to detect when the first item is selected, like where index = 1 or something. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [`JComboBox#getSelectedIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex())

You could also use [`JComboBox#getSelectedItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem())

You could use [`ItemEvent#getItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getItem()) which will return the selected item, but you'd need the combo box to determine the index of the item...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its not working. If I have two items that are called the same thing, then when I click on either of them it returns the same index... Being the index of the first instance of that item.

Comment: getSelectedIndex will return the index of the selected item regardless of name. The other choice is to wrap each element into a unique object wrapper